# Get tags post in url with php

Tags: php

I have a problem for call get post URL, where I call post by "Tags" not display.

my url :

localhost/asd/list/**movie**

i want call tags "movie" but not display, i use code :

```
$tags = $_GET['Tags'];
$test = "SELECT * FROM `test1` ORDER BY Tags = '$tags' DESC";
```

I want to display what I'm calling in URL.

maybe someone here can help my problem.

Comment: $test = "SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE  Tags = '$tags' ORDER BY Tags DESC";

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter data matching a condition use `WHERE` clause

Therefore your updated query would look like:

```
$test = "SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE Tags = '".$tags."' ORDER BY DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

in your url use:
localhost/asd/list/**?Tags=movie**

and your sql command 
$test = "SELECT * FROM `test1` ORDER BY Tags = '**$Tags**' DESC";

Be attention on T in uppercase.